php no longer working
As of the last few days php stopped working on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 installation. Have there been unattended upgrades that broke it. BTW I had php7.4.33 intentionally installed to support dokuwiki, which does not support php8. When I found php8 had been installed (by unattended updates?) I rolled it back but php still does not work.
Coincidentally I began having trouble with MQTT connecting from ESP32 system on a chip devices. Could that just be coincidental?

use docker or some other container manager if want to have trouble free system upgrades

Oops. actually I have 22.04.4. I upgraded to php8 but php still does not work.

I solved the problem by purging  php7.4 and installing php8.1, along with some required modules and other tweaks! I still mystifies me what unattended upgrades broke this in the first place, unless php8.3 was part of that update.

The default php on 22.04 is 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 so you'd done something to your system to change defaults & your sources were non-standard as php8.3 is available only for noble in Ubuntu default repositories...   Changes you made to your system are almost guaranteed to be the cause.

I did nothing before it broke last weekend out of the blue. I gave pints of blood and pounds of flesh to fix it. I strongly suspect unattended upgrades, since I had php7.4 a week ago and suddenly found php8.4 on my PC. Doesn't that say it all? There is a remote possibility I ran apt update and upgrade, but I don't remember doing it or having a reason for it.. I have now set update-alternatives to php8.1,

I suggest exploring how php7.4 was put on the system, as that is not provided with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS... ie. your system was changed with additional (unofficial) sources added most likely. Run sudo apt update or view sources & contrast the output your system provides now, and how it would vary to a standard install etc as the versions you mention imply non-Ubuntu official software (such as consequence of corrupted sources made by user with sudo rights)

I intentionally had downgraded to php7.4 as the then latest version of dokuwiki did not support php8. A new release does.

Explore your provided details; as they highlight the problem you're having as being self-induced. You report getting a non-official 22.04 package installed as a consequence of you intentionally downgrading the same package... ie. check how you installed your downgraded package & your sources (what I tried to say before reworded). From your description I'd run sudo apt update OR look at your sources & examine the changes (over standard) first, or command history of what changes were made to your system relating to php (esp. sources related). The unattended upgrades use your changes to sources

Up until last weekend my php and Apache installation was working perfectly until the suspected unattended upgrade. Ergo I don't think this was self inflicted other than my desire to keep my system consistent with the apps I had installed. I think this case is closed now.
